# Returning Set[Class[A]] over Set[Class[_]]

Tags: scala

On Scala 2.10.4, given the following trait and case classes:

```
scala> trait Parent
defined trait Parent

scala> case class Girl() extends Parent
defined class Girl

scala> case class Boy() extends Parent
defined class Boy
```

I'm trying to define a method, `f`, that produces a `Set[Class[A]]` where `A`'s type is `A <: Parent`.

```
scala> def f[A <: Parent]: Set[Class[A]] = Set[Class[A]](classOf[Boy], classOf[Girl])
<console>:12: error: type mismatch;
 found   : Class[Boy](classOf[$Boy])
 required: Class[A]
       def f[A <: Parent]: Set[Class[A]] = Set[Class[A]](classOf[Boy], classOf[Girl])
                                                                ^
<console>:12: error: type mismatch;
 found   : Class[Girl](classOf[$Girl])
 required: Class[A]
       def f[A <: Parent]: Set[Class[A]] = Set[Class[A]](classOf[Boy], classOf[Girl])
```

But, I can make it work if I use, what I believe is the "wildcard":

```
scala> def g[A <: Parent]: Set[Class[_]] = Set[Class[_]](classOf[Boy], classOf[Girl])
g: [A <: Parent]=> Set[Class[_]]
```

And it works:

```
scala> g
res5: Set[Class[_]] = Set(class Boy, class Girl)
```

Why did the first approach fail, but the second succeeded? Lastly, is there any risk (to type safety) using `Class[_]` in the above definition of `g`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that `Class[A]` is invariant in its type parameter. So `Class[Boy]` is not a `Class[Parent]`. The compiler will warn you of this if you set an explicit return type of `Set[Class[Parent]]`.

```
scala> def f[_ <: Parent]: Set[Class[Parent]] = Set(classOf[Boy], classOf[Girl])
<console>:24: error: type mismatch;
 found   : Class[Boy](classOf[$Boy])
 required: Class[Parent]
Note: Boy <: Parent, but Java-defined class Class is invariant in type T.
You may wish to investigate a wildcard type such as `_ <: Parent`. (SLS 3.2.10)
       def f[_ <: Parent]: Set[Class[Parent]] = Set(classOf[Boy], classOf[Girl])
```

The following method uses existential types, which essentially means you don't care what the type is. `_` is a completely unbound, and the type parameter `A` is superfluous.

```
def g[A <: Parent]: Set[Class[_]] = Set[Class[_]](classOf[Boy], classOf[Girl])
```

You might as well write:

```
def g: Set[Class[_]] = Set[Class[_]](classOf[Boy], classOf[Girl])
```

> Lastly, is there any risk (to type safety) using Class[_] in the above definition of g?

Type safety has pretty much gone out the window at this point, because `_` can be anything. `Boy`, `Girl`, `Parent`, `Any`, `Toaster`, ...

I think the best you can hope for is to heed the warning and get something like this:

```
def g: Set[Class[_ <: Parent]] = Set(classOf[Boy], classOf[Girl])
```

This will at least ensure that you have a `Set` with elements bounded above by `Parent`. Exactly what you intend to do with it, I don't know.

Comment: Can you suggest any type safe alternative please?

Comment: What do you want to do with this `Set`? I'm not sure if it can be any better than my latest edit.  The invariance of `Class` is very limiting.